# Center images within grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a grid to display images of a team. I have a grid of images and I need to position my bottom 2 images below the top 2 middle images - basically centralizing the bottom 2. How can I achieve this? I've added my HTML and CSS below. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

```css
.team-grids .team-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="w3l-heading">
      <h3>Our Team</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="team-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Edwards Doe</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML code?

Comment: i think that adding, display: flex instead of display:block and justify-content: center would do the trick

Comment: @AmineKOUIS - I've added it

Comment: @MiguelCruz that didn't work :(. Isn't moving the images at all

Comment: The code you've shared does not produce the effect you're showing. Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding this:

```
 .team-grids {
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

edited: my bad, pls try this one. 
add  `justify-content-md-center`

```css
.team-grids .team-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 
 <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="w3l-heading">
      <h3>Our Team</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row team-row  justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://gyazo.com/2fac18f9f6395e4815234d5512de6cba.png" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Edwards Doe</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://gyazo.com/2fac18f9f6395e4815234d5512de6cba.png" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://gyazo.com/2fac18f9f6395e4815234d5512de6cba.png" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://gyazo.com/2fac18f9f6395e4815234d5512de6cba.png" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://gyazo.com/2fac18f9f6395e4815234d5512de6cba.png" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://gyazo.com/2fac18f9f6395e4815234d5512de6cba.png" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Done. Just need to add `text-align: center;` , see the example below :D

```css
.team-grids .team-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="w3l-heading">
      <h3>Our Team</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="team-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/Images/t1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Edwards Doe</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/Images/t1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these rules `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` to `.team-row` class like below

```
.team-row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Run the Code snippet bellow :

```css
.team-row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="w3l-heading">
      <h3>Our Team</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="team-row">
      <div class="col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Edwards Doe</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.team-grids .team-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="w3l-heading">
      <h3>Our Team</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="team-row row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img mx-auto">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Edwards Doe</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img mx-auto">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img mx-auto">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img mx-auto">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img mx-auto">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 team-grids">
        <div class="team-img mx-auto">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
          <div class="captn">
            <div class="captn-top">
              <h4>Mark Sophia</h4>
              <p>description</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Three changes to your code:

1) Add class `row` and `justify-content-center` alongwith `team-row`. Columns are always used in combination with rows in Bootstrap.

2) Add class `img-fluid`, because `img-responsive` is a Bootstrap 3 class which is changed to `img-fluid` in Bootstrap 4.

3) Add class `mx-auto` to `team-img` in case you need to center the image in column. For text, you can use `text-center`.